# isFinite of space giving true value

Tags: javascript, type-coercion

I am trying to validate a price field. I was trying this:

```
var productId = document.getElementById("productId");
var productName = document.getElementById("productName");
var productPrice = document.getElementById("price");

alert(isFinite(productPrice.value));

if(isNaN(productPrice.value)||!isFinite(productPrice.value)){
    error = document.getElementById("priceError");
    error.innerHTML = "Please enter correct value";
    productPrice.style.border="thin solid red";
}else{
    error = document.getElementById("priceError");
    error.innerHTML = "";
}
```

The line alert is giving me true when the input is space/ multiple spaces only.
This is my HTML page.

```
<td>Price</td>
<td><input type = "text" id = "price" size = "14"/></td>
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you have in `productPrice.value`?

Comment: `isFinite` of any _String_ where `+string` is not `+`/`-` `Infinity` or `NaN` will be `true`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why this happens i cant say, but this code should solve the problem

```
isFinite(parseFloat(" ")) // false
// because -->
parseFloat(" "); // => result NaN
// tested in Chrome 27+ on Win7
```

in the MDN refernce of isNaN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)
it says

```
isNaN(" ");     // false: a string with spaces is converted to 0 which is not NaN
```

***Update:***

in the Reference of isFinite found [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite) it states that isFinite only returns false if the argument is:

- `NaN`
- positive infinity, (`Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY`)
- negative infinity (`Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`)
  In any other Case it returns true. (like Paul S mentioned)

Now i Think i got all loose ends, and in that course learned something. :)

Answer (score 1):

with [`window.isFinite`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite), you must be aware of the issues that [`window.isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite) suffers from when [coercing types](http://webreflection.blogspot.se/2010/10/javascript-coercion-demystified.html).

> window.IsNaN Summary
>
> Determines whether a value is NaN or not. Be careful, this function is
>   broken. You may be interested in ECMAScript 6 Number.isNaN.
>
> Examples
>
> ```
> isNaN(NaN);       // true 
> isNaN(undefined); // true 
> isNaN({});        // true
>
> isNaN(true);      // false
> isNaN(null);      // false
> isNaN(37);       // false
>
> // strings 
> isNaN("37");      // false: "37" is converted to the number 37 which is not NaN 
> isNaN("37.37");   // false: "37.37" is converted to the number 37.37 which is not NaN
> isNaN("");        // false: the empty string is converted to 0 which is not NaN 
> isNaN(" ");  // false: a string with spaces is converted to 0 which is not NaN
> // This is a false positive and the reason why isNaN is not entirely reliable
>
> isNaN("blabla")   // true: "blabla" is converted to a number. Parsing this as a number fails and returns NaN
> ```

In ECMAScript 6 there are new methods [`Number.isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) and [`Number.isFinite`](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3anumber.isfinite) that address these issues. ([of course these are not available in many browsers](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/es6/))

`Number.isFinite` is equivalent to

```
function isFinite(number) {
    return typeof number === "number" && window.isFinite(number);
}
```

So as a solution, you would need to consider something like this (cross-browser).

*Note: this solution will still allow you to enter hexadecimal or scientific notations, "0xA", "1e10"*

Javascript

```
function isFinite(number) {
    return typeof number === "number" && window.isFinite(number);
}

function trim(string) {
    return string.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
}

var price = document.getElementById("price");

price.onchange = function (e) {
    var evt = e || window.event,
        target = evt.target || evt.srcElement,
        value = trim(target.value) || "NaN",
        number = +value;

    console.log("number:", number);
    console.log("isFinite:", isFinite(number));
}
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/25MUu/)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using reqular expression.

Try this.

```
function validatePrice() {
    var el = document.getElementById('price');
    if ( 
         el.value.length < 14 && 
         /^ *\+?\d+ *$/.test( el.value )
       )
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This function checks if the input is positive integer. I didnt know if you want floated values also.
If you do, switch the regex to this /^ *+?\d+((.|,)\d+)? *$/